# Unable to resolve dependency 'JSON.NET'

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, nuget, twilio

I am trying to install the package Twilio.Client on my machine for an upcoming project, but I keep getting the following error:

[image: Unable to resolve dependency 'JSON.NET']

I also tried using the PM Console but got the same dependency error. Where do I need to be looking to manually resolve this dependency? I checked the packages.config file and there aren't any json packages. I tried installing json.net from nuGet but that didn't work either. I'm pretty much at a loss here. I would really like to use this library. Thank you all.

Comment: Check your references, is it there? Better yet, is it there with a yellow triangle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like something wrong with the latest version. 3.5.1 works as of now. You can use this to install and use the [Twilio client library](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/client).

Use this in the PM console: `Install-Package Twilio.Client -Version 3.5.1`

Comment: Hey Sean, can I send you a t-shirt to say thanks for offering your assistance in the Twilio community here? Send an email to mspeir@twilio.com for details.

Answer (score 0):

JSON.Net is contained in the package called Newtonsoft.JSON, check it out [here](https://www.nuget.org/packages/newtonsoft.json/)